# Salvando dados em API Angular

Tags: javascript, laravel, angular, api

Preciso salvar um conjunto de dados através de uma API.

Já tentei passar os dados de diversas maneiras mas não tive êxito. Sempre dá o erro:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":404,"statusText":"Not Found","url":

Segue abaixo o código.

```
//metodo para salvar os dados ao fazer o submit

async onCheck() {
    console.log(this.eventGuest);
    this.eventService.saveInvite(this.events,this.eventGuest);
}


//metodo para fazer a requisição no endpoint

saveInvite(id_events, eventGuest):Promise<any>{
return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
    this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'api/event/'+id_events+'/invite', eventGuest).then((response)=>{
        res(response);
    }).catch((err)=>{
       rej(err);
    });
}

//caminho da rota da api feita no Laravel

Route::post('/event/{event}/invite','EventController@invite')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: Status 404 significa rota não encontrada. Verifique sua URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro 404 'ignorantemente' falando, significa que essa requisição não achou um endPoint, ou seja, verifique essa url que você está passando, pois ele não está encontrando o servidor.